# Find all substrings from a string by deleting characters from it

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Problem Description :
I need to create all substrings from a string by deleting letters from it without re-arranging the rest of the letters. For example, "us" is a substring of "substring", but "gs" is not . Duplicates should be counted. For example, "peep" has two substrings "pep", corresponding to the two choices of "e". The code below I ran does not give me desired output.

```
subString[s_String] := StringCases[s, {_, __}, Overlaps -> All]
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: subString[s_String] := Map[StringJoin, Subsets[Characters[s]]]

Comment: I think you are correct, I added remove the empty element in the list in code below. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the below code is correct, contributed from user3257842

```
DeleteCases[Map[StringJoin, Subsets[Characters[s]]], ""]
```

The code above will give us the non-empty sublists of a string by deleting characters from it.

Thanks.

Comment: The null string always appears first in the list so 
Drop[Map[StringJoin, Subsets[Characters[s]]], 1]
would also work.